# Eliminating the Parameter

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Eliminate the parameter of the given parametric equations and write the resulting Cartesian equation. $x=e^t - 1$, $y=e^{2t}$
I got $y=(x+1)^2$ is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: It is correct that  points described by the parametric equations necessarily satisfy the Cartesian equation. But it may be that the first set of points is a strict subset of the second set of points. That's because the steps you used in eliminating the parameter are not reversible.

Answer (score 2):

When eliminating $t$, we get

$$e^t=x+1$$

$$y=e^{2t}= (e^t)^2 = (x+1)^2$$

But as $t$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ $x$ goes from $-1$ to $\infty$, so the resulting domain is $x\gt-1$.

We would also get $y=(x+1)^2$ from parametric equations
$$x=-e^t-1$$
$$y=e^{2t}$$

but in that case the domain would be $x<-1$.